# How do I display the tree-view according to the source directory?

Tags: doxygen

I have two source directory, c++ and python, and I want to show these two directories separately in the tree-view,  like this, rather than next to each other.

- my_project
  -- python_dir
  -- c++_dir

I looked at the official documentation but couldn't find it

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Please sow what you want to see and what you see now (you say " I want to show these two directories separately in the tree-view, like this, rather than next to each other"  but it is unclear.

Comment: Cross posting to https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/10444?

Comment: doxygen version is 1.9.1
i want to say that:
-my_project
-- python_dir
-- cpp_dir
but, what i say now is that:
- my_porject
-- class
--- classlist 
---- python_dir
---- cpp_dir

Comment: Doxygen 1.9.1 is a bit older, the current doxygen version is 1.9.8 Please ad some images to your question with the current and wanted situation and a small example so we can reproduce the problem.